# Rails Single Resource as Nested Resource of Two Other Resources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I have a business, a catalog and a product resource.

A business has a catalog and a number of products.

A catalog will always belong to a business.

A product may or may not be under a catalog.

The products table both has catalog_id and business_id.

How will I form the route so that I can allow a product without a catalog and a product belonging to a catalog, i.e., these URLs:

- businesses/:business_id/catalogs/:catalog_id/products/:id
- businesses/:business_id/products/:id

I have already allowed the latter using this:

```
resources :businesses do
    resources :catalogs

    resources :products do
      resources :images
      end
  end
```

how do I modify it to allow the first URL?

I know I'm just missing something simple, feel free to close this and refer to a duplicate if there is one.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using 3 level nested routes if that's the business requirement, but it is [not the *rails* way](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). You can achieve the effect of having 3 level nested routes using just 2 and have more restful routes.

Comment: @garbagecollection mind giving an answer on how to do that? achieving 3 level nested routes with 2?

Comment: [Check out the routes of this project I am current working on](https://github.com/serv/minforum). I struggled with very similar problems you went through. Currently, associations between 3 models, Forum, Topic, and Post work very well without error. A Forum has many Topics. A Topic has many Posts. So 3 level deep would work for me here. But since 2 level deep takes care of the problem, I didn't bother using 3 level deep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you were almost there:

```
resources :businesses do
    resources :catalogs do
      resources :products do
        resources :images
      end
    end

    resources :products do
      resources :images
    end
end
```

The same way you did for businesses/products you can also do for businesses/catalogs/products, there is no difference, just nest the resources.

Comment: Also try not to nest too deeply. This is covered in a disclaimer on [Rails Routing - Nested Resources][1]


  [1]: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources